# Anitpodal Map for Sphere, Mean Value

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Let $n ≥ 2$ and $g : \mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{R}^2$
be a map such that $g(−x) = −g(x)$ for all $x$. Prove
that there is a point $x_0$ in $\mathbb{S}^
n$
such that $g(x_0) = 0.$

How to proceed?

Comment: One may as well take $n=2$. This is the Borsuk-Ulam theorem in $2$ dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $S^n$ contains $S^2$.  Restrict $g$ to this $S^2$, where it is still the case $g(-x)=-g(x)$.